# What is the benifit of using `url` over `text` on the Web Share API?

Tags: ios, safari, web-share

I am wondering if there is any benefit using `url` over `text` on the Web Share API?

Let me explain why I am asking this:

I am using the [Web Share API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/share) to share a URL to my website accompanied with some text like this:

```
navigator.share({
  title: 'Foobar',
  text: 'Foo foo bar bar!',
  url: 'https://example.com'
})
```

It works perfectly fine. Except for some long existing bug on iOS Safari that prevents the URL specified in the `options.url` from being pasteable in for example an `input` or `textarea` element. Which renders its functionality partially useless.

Now, a workaround would be to just put the link in the `options.text` like this instead:

```
navigator.share({
  title: 'Foobar',
  text: 'Foo foo bar bar! https://example.com',
})
```

So there's that. But I couldn't find any information on the possible drawbacks this workaround might have.

Answer (score 0):

It's very much up to the user agent (i.e., the browser) and the receiving app to decide what it makes with the shared data.

Possible values are:

- `url`: A string representing a URL to be shared.
- `text`: A string representing text to be shared.
- `title`: A string representing a title to be shared. **May be ignored by the target.**

Note the bold part. If your favorite app (in the sense of: the app that you expect the majority of your users to share to) behaves in an undesired way, try changing the way you populate the different fields.

Comment: Yeah, this is what I got as well. But apparently the `url` can be ignored as well. But that doesn't answer my actual question: what _might_ be the benefit of using `url` over `text`. And what could be possible drawbacks to just put your url inside the `text` option.

Comment: As I said, this may greatly depend on the app. Most apps are very forgiving and just concatenate everything together, as, for example, in a tweet on Twitter. There _may_ be apps that strictly expect things in `url` to be actual URLs, but the spec only [requires](https://w3c.github.io/web-share/#sharedata-dictionary) the `url` field to be a [`USVString`](https://webidl.spec.whatwg.org/#idl-USVString).